# MySQL Show records of current user + users that he is a parent of

Tags: mysql

how do I go about writing the MySQL code to get records of the current logged in user and on top of that, the users that he is a parent of?

```
    user_id  |  username  |  parent_user_id
    ---------+------------+-----------------
    1        |  alvin     |  NULL
    2        |  gary      |  1
    3        |  tom       |  1
```

We log into to the user alvin and have basic MySQL statement... (pseudo code)
This selects orders that belong to Alvin.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM orders
    WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['loggedUser']
```

How do I go about writing the Statement that also display orders from Gary and Tom (due to the parent-child relationship defined in the user's table? Or for lack of a better term, like a team leader/team restricted viewing.

*Also like to add that the orders table only stores information and a single username field to store which user the order belongs to

Many thanks!

Comment: How many levels does your hierarchy have? If it's only a single level you can do with a self-join otherwise you need to write a stored procedure because MySQL still lacks recursive queries.

Comment: Do you mean if theres more than single level
Gary -> Alvin -> Thomas (Gary is a parent of alvin, and alvin is a parent of thomas) that the self-joins won't work?

Comment: More or less, yes. Because you would need one self join for each *possible* level. If you don't know the number of levels (or at least an upper limit) this is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! So if I know how many levels there are possible, self joins should work too right? so if theres only 2 levels at maximum, i could modify the self joins to check for parent-child relationship a second time

Comment: Yes. For each *possible* level you need to use another self (outer!) join.

Comment: Thanks again so much! Do you have a suggestion to which might be a better solution of the 3 posted below? Though there are only actually 2 methods in reality

Comment: @user3448267  If you have arbitrator level hierarchy then you need to write stored procedure, all below answer are for single level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['loggedUser']
OR 
user_id IN (SELECT user_id 
            FROM users
            WHERE parent_user_id= $_SESSION['loggedUser'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT child.user_id,child.username
FROM orders main
  left join orders child on child .parent_user_id=main.user_id  
WHERE main.user_id = $_SESSION['loggedUser']
```

Answer (score 0):

This don't have to be complicated (for single level of hierarchy)

```
SELECT *
    FROM orders
    WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['loggedUser']
    OR parent_user_id = $_SESSION['loggedUser']
```